# C++ Read file with only numbers

Tags: c++, regex, file, int, double

I'm writing a c++ program that reads in a file. The file *should* contain only numbers, and if it doesn't, it just throws an error.

I currently can loop through the file and lines and get each token and tell what each token is, but seeing as I am a beginner to c++ I don't know how to only include the numbers.

An example file would be:

```
1 2 3 4 5.645 50603 0.543 5.0
100 5.555555 600 1 0 5

               67.64

65.6                                 70

                <spaces>

            90
```

I tried looking up several ways, and I tried using a space for a delimeter, but I have to account for an empty line of spaces, which a delimeter messes up.

**I have tried these methods so far:**

This method takes in "5.0", but only prints it as "5":
    double i;

```
while(fin >> i)
{
    cout << " Token value: " << i << endl;
}
```

This method will not take a newline/newline with spaces only:

```
int i = 0;
int lineNumber = 1;
char token;
const char* const delimeter = " ";
while (fin.good())
{
    // read line into memory with a max length of 10 characters per line
    char buffer[1024];
    fin.getline(buffer, 1024);

    // array to hold the values until compution
    char* token[1024] = {};


    // strtok splits a string into tokens
    // get the first token
    token[0] = strtok(buffer, delimeter);

    // check if the first line is blank (blank is set to 0)
    if (token[0])
    {
        for (i = 1; i < 1024; i++)
        {
            // get more tokens
            token[i] = strtok(0, delimeter);

            // check if there are no more tokens
            if (!token[i])
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {

        // if (token[j] == " ") cout << " this is a space" << endl;
        cout << " Line: " << lineNumber << " --- Token[" << j << "] = " << token[j] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    i++;
    lineNumber++;

}
```

Any suggestions for a beginner at c++ (I have Java experience) ?

EDIT: Period corner case:

There seems to be no recognition of a period if it is on the last line and the only character. It doesn't error nor print out the period:

```
12 35 67777.75
54433
.
```

However, it does throw the correct error if it's like this:

```
12 36 67777.75
.
54433
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Added code I have tried so far.

Comment: Is it important to read the file line by line or do you just need to read in the numbers one by one?

Comment: Whichever is more efficient. There is no constraint regarding whether to read them in one by one or line by line, but in the end I need to have them all to be able to compute the average of them.

Comment: Is it important that you filter non-numbers out in C++? Otherwise you might filter the input file through something like `grep -e "(\d+\s*)+" 'yourfile.txt' > 'yourfile.new.txt'` leaving only numbers separated with spaces there.

Comment: Sadly, yes. I must take a file with any possible characters in it, and make sure they are numbers, and then do functionality with the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful to you.

You can read in the numbers one by one this way:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("mydatafile.txt");

    // check for errors
    if(!fin.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: opening input file:" << std::endl;
        return 1; // error code 1
    }

    double d;
    while(fin >> d) // skips spaces and newlines automatically
    {
        // do what you want with the number d here (print it?)
        std::cout << d << '\n';
    }

    // Did we read all the data or was there a problem?
    if(!fin.eof())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: failed to read all the data from input file:" << std::endl;
        return 2; // error code 2
    }

}
```

The `while(fin >> d)` is very idiomatic. It ensured that the body of the loop is only executed if the read was successful. It takes into account that errors happen **during** the read.

**EDIT:**

Added test to see if the file was read all the way to the end or not

**EDIT:**

As an alternative you can read each entry from the text file into a `std::string` and then test if the `std::string` converts into a `double` or not:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("mydatafile.txt");

    // check for errors
    if(!fin.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: opening input file:" << std::endl;
        return 1; // error code 1
    }

    std::string s;
    while(fin >> s) // skips spaces and newlines automatically
    {
        // now see if we can convert s into a number by
        // turning s into an input stream and read it into a number

        double d;
        if(std::istringstream(s) >> d)
        {
            // do what you want with the number d here (print it?)
            std::cout << d << '\n';
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: bad data: \"" << s << "\"" << std::endl;
            // continue? Or not?
        }
    }

    if(!fin.eof())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: failed to read all the data from input file:" << std::endl;
        return 2; // error code 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a while-loop, you could use a for-loop to restrict the scope of d as in for (double d; fin >> d; ) { /* stuff using d */ }.

Comment: This is helpful, and works, except when I use letters. I need to make sure that the file ONLY contains numbers, and so when I put a letter into the file, it gets up to that letter, then just fails, which it should. But then there is no way to check whether it failed correctly or not. 

    if (stream.fail())

occurs yes if the file found something not a number, but also fails if the stream completed and then finished, so it gets thrown in both cases.

Is there any completed or finished statement for an ifstream to see if it successfully parsed through it?

Comment: @Sej If the whole file is read properly then the eof (end of file) flag should be set. You can test that with `fin.eof()`. I'll add that to the example. Alternatively you can read in strings rather than numbers and try to convert each string to a number. If one of the strings fails, report the failure and continue or stop whichever you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One thing I tested (since I'm reading in doubles) is what happens when I give a file like this:

I edited my post to show the corner case.

That throws an error which is correct, but there seems to be some corner case where if there is a period on the very last line, then it doesn't throw an error nor print out the period.

Would there be a good way to go about fixing that?

Comment: @Sej The second example I gave should allow you to continue reading if you find a stray "." in the file. But if the data is malformed there is only so much you can do.